Pytorch got Non-reproducible results after adding activation function (i.e., ReLU)
I am unable to reproduce my results in PyTorch after adding a nn.ReLU(). I am sure that the problem must be here instead of other places, since I have tested with ablation hundreds of times. It is weird that the activation function does affect reproducibility. Even though I replaced the nn.ReLU() with torch.max(), it does NOT work yet.
Setting deterministic experiments :
seed = 0
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
os.environ['CUBLAS_WORKSPACE_CONFIG'] = ':4096:8'
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = False
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)

Problematic code :
class DiffNet_Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, data, social_data, emb_size, n_layers):
        super(DiffNet_Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.social_data = social_data
        self.latent_size = emb_size
        self.layers = n_layers
        self.norm_inter = data.norm_inter
        self.embedding_dict = self._init_model()
        self.sparse_norm_inter = TorchGraphInterface.convert_sparse_mat_to_tensor(self.norm_inter).cuda()
        self.sparse_social_adj = TorchGraphInterface.convert_sparse_mat_to_tensor(self.social_data.tocsr()).cuda()

    def _init_model(self):
        initializer = nn.init.xavier_uniform_
        embedding_dict = {'weight%d'%k: nn.Parameter(initializer(torch.empty(2*self.latent_size, self.latent_size))) for k in range(self.layers)}
        embedding_dict['user_emb'] = nn.Parameter(initializer(torch.empty(self.data.user_num, self.latent_size)))
        embedding_dict['item_emb'] = nn.Parameter(initializer(torch.empty(self.data.item_num, self.latent_size)))
        embedding_dict = nn.ParameterDict(embedding_dict)
        return embedding_dict

    def forward(self):
        user_embeddings = self.embedding_dict['user_emb']
        item_embeddings = self.embedding_dict['item_emb'] # null operation
        for k in range(self.layers):
            new_user_embeddings = torch.sparse.mm(self.sparse_social_adj, user_embeddings)
            user_embeddings = torch.matmul(torch.cat([new_user_embeddings, user_embeddings], dim=1), self.embedding_dict['weight%d'%k])
            user_embeddings = nn.ReLU()(user_embeddings) # HERE!!!!!!! If I comment this line out, it can be reproducible 
        final_user_embeddings = user_embeddings + torch.sparse.mm(self.sparse_norm_inter, item_embeddings)
        return final_user_embeddings, item_embeddings.data

user_embeddings = nn.ReLU()(user_embeddings) makes the results non-reproducible.
Result W/ ReLU():
2024-05-06 11:25:48,930 - DiffNet - INFO - ###Evaluation Results###
2024-05-06 11:25:48,930 - DiffNet - INFO - ['Top 10\n', 'Hit Ratio:0.15284\n', 'Precision:0.13263\n', 'Recall:0.15036\n', 'NDCG:0.16989\n']
2024-05-06 11:18:04,953 - DiffNet - INFO - ###Evaluation Results###
2024-05-06 11:18:04,953 - DiffNet - INFO - ['Top 10\n', 'Hit Ratio:0.15507\n', 'Precision:0.13457\n', 'Recall:0.15272\n', 'NDCG:0.17073\n']
Result W/O ReLU():
2024-05-06 12:34:17,763 - DiffNet - INFO - ###Evaluation Results###
2024-05-06 12:34:17,763 - DiffNet - INFO - ['Top 10\n', 'Hit Ratio:0.14373\n', 'Precision:0.12473\n', 'Recall:0.14033\n', 'NDCG:0.16247\n']
2024-05-06 12:33:55,630 - DiffNet - INFO - ###Evaluation Results###
2024-05-06 12:33:55,631 - DiffNet - INFO - ['Top 10\n', 'Hit Ratio:0.14373\n', 'Precision:0.12473\n', 'Recall:0.14033\n', 'NDCG:0.16247\n']
This is the copy of code DiffNet, a social recommender.

Now I have tried other activation function (e.g., sigmoid, tanh). Interestingly, these activation functions do not affect the reproducibility of results. It makes me really have no ideas about this problems.
